# How to create a GeneralName with pyasn1?

Tags: python, asn.1, pyasn1

Being fairly new to pyasn1 (pyasn1 0.4.8, pyasn1-modules 0.2.8) and ASN.1 in general, I'm trying to construct a `GeneralName`:

```
>>> from pyasn1.codec.der.encoder import encode
>>> from pyasn1.type import char
>>> from pyasn1_modules import rfc2459
>>> from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import (
...     AttributeTypeAndValue, GeneralName, Name, RelativeDistinguishedName, RDNSequence)
>>> 
>>> rdn = RelativeDistinguishedName()
>>> attr_type_and_value = AttributeTypeAndValue()
>>> attr_type_and_value['type'] = rfc2459.id_at_countryName
>>> attr_type_and_value['value'] = encode(char.UTF8String('DE'))
>>> rdn.append(attr_type_and_value)
>>> 
>>> rdn_sequence = RDNSequence()
>>> rdn_sequence.append(rdn)
>>> 
>>> name = Name()
>>> name[0] = rdn_sequence
>>> 
>>> general_name = GeneralName()
>>> general_name['directoryName'] = name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 2246, in __setitem__
    self.setComponentByName(idx, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 2413, in setComponentByName
    idx, value, verifyConstraints, matchTags, matchConstraints
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 3119, in setComponentByPosition
    Set.setComponentByPosition(self, idx, value, verifyConstraints, matchTags, matchConstraints)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 2601, in setComponentByPosition
    raise error.PyAsn1Error('Component value is tag-incompatible: %r vs %r' % (value, componentType))
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: Component value is tag-incompatible: <Name value object, tagSet=<TagSet object, untagged>, [...]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 2250, in __setitem__
    raise KeyError(sys.exc_info()[1])
KeyError: PyAsn1Error('Component value is tag-incompatible: <Name value object, tagSet=<TagSet object, untagged>, [...]
```

I truncated the very long exception messages. The essence is, as I understand it, that the supplied Name object is untagged while certain tags are expected. I can work around the exception by using `general_name.setComponentByName('directoryName', name, matchTags=False)`, but I'm not sure whether this just turns off a desired/important check and will bite me at a later point. The pyasn1 `Tag` and `TagSet` documentation didn't enlighten me, but that's possibly because I haven't really understood the purpose of tags in ASN.1.

So, my main question is: How do I correctly create a `GeneralName` with pyasn1? Subquestions:

- What's the purpose of tags in ASN.1? I thought of them as type specifiers (as in: "this is an integer, boolean, sequence, etc."), but apparently I'm missing something.
- I use a `UTF8String`. Decoding a time-stamping response created with OpenSSL, I found that a `PrintableString` was used in a `GeneralName`. I intuitively chose the former, but can that lead to a problem (depending on the context of use)?

Comment: Can you try name[''] instead of name[0] ...

Comment: @YaFred Same exception.

Comment: general_name['directoryName'][''] = rdn_sequence

Comment: You may want to open an issue on https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1/issues (for me, it's all about accessing choice alternatives that are described in pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 ... so there may be a bug)

Comment: `general_name['directoryName']['']` does indeed help and it avoids the manual creation of the `Name` object.

Comment: But you still have the exception ... ?

Comment: @YaFred No, the exception is gone.

Comment: Excellent, I'll add a proper answer to your others questions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug or a limitation of pyasn1

I wonder if this is related to this: https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1/issues/179

The [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459) says

```
GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
           otherName                       [0]     OtherName,
           rfc822Name                      [1]     IA5String,
           dNSName                         [2]     IA5String,
           x400Address                     [3]     ORAddress,
           directoryName                   [4]     Name,
           ediPartyName                    [5]     EDIPartyName,
           uniformResourceIdentifier       [6]     IA5String,
           iPAddress                       [7]     OCTET STRING,
           registeredID                    [8]     OBJECT IDENTIFIER}

Name            ::=   CHOICE { -- only one possibility for now --
                                 rdnSequence  RDNSequence }

RDNSequence     ::=   SEQUENCE OF RelativeDistinguishedName
```

With ASN.1 there is usually a compilation step that generates some code. With pyasn1, you either write the code yourself or include some modules.

As you include [pyasn1_modules.rfc2459](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules/blob/master/pyasn1_modules/rfc2459.py), the only work is to use the classes.

Your writing looks very legitimate

```
>>> rdn_sequence = RDNSequence()
>>> rdn_sequence.append(rdn)
>>> 
>>> name = Name()
>>> name[0] = rdn_sequence
>>> 
>>> general_name = GeneralName()
>>> general_name['directoryName'] = name
```

But it seems that pyasn1 only allows the shorthand access

```
>>> rdn_sequence = RDNSequence()
>>> rdn_sequence.append(rdn)
>>> 
>>> general_name = GeneralName()
>>> general_name['directoryName'][''] = rdn_sequence
```

I think both should be allowed ...

As for the tags: as you are using the pyasn1 modules, you should not have to worry about them. They are needed to encode the messages when the encoding form is Tag/Length/Value (So, BER, CER and DER ASN.1 encoding rules).

As for the types (like UTF8String): you can't change them, they have to be the types you read from the ASN.1 Specification. They have a (so called universal) tag associated with them and your encoded message won't be understood by the receiver.

Note that there is a slight discrepancy between the implementation of Name and the spec (the spec has a named Type while the implementation has no name). This was allowed in the olden days.

```
class Name(univ.Choice):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('', RDNSequence())
    )
```

But I don't think this is a problem.